# What does the orange keys mean in keyboard viewer?

Tags: keyboard, ui

I use the keyboard viewer as a cheat sheet so I can guide myself in the horrible fields of OSX keymaps and I realised that pressing some keys will display a few keys in orange. What does that color indicate?

[image: Orange keys in OS X keyboard viewer]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those keys in orange are so-called dead keys. It's a key that does not necessarily generate a complete character by itself but may modify the character generated by the key struck immediately after.

The usage of those dead keys in a text editor or in the Terminal is usually indicated by a yellowish background. You may then enter the main character you want to modify to finally get the desired one.

Not all combinations of a dead key and a normal key are used. Typing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> (=<kbd>~</kbd>) <kbd>n</kbd> will result in a 'ñ'. But <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> (=<kbd>~</kbd>) <kbd>t</kbd> just gives '~t'.

Comment: You are right. After you press the dead key the keyboard viewer also shows the modified keys. E.g. pressing `¨` will display `ö` instead of `o` in it. Textfields also highlight the entered dead key in orange.

Answer (score 3):

The orange represent accent characters to add to the next inputed letter. It is functionally equivalent to accessing [OSX’s accent menu](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18436?locale=en_US) - holding down a key and seeing:

[image]

For example. So, alternatively, you can type <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> followed by<kbd>u</kbd> to add a diaresis to the letter <kbd>ü</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It means that those symbols overlay themselves onto whatever letter you next. For example, <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> followed by <kbd>u</kbd> would type ü, rather than ¨u.